# How to insert NULL value in image column using C# code

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, image, stored-procedures

I have the following code

```
cmd. Parameters. AddWithValue("@Password",
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.Password))
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : member.Password);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",
    (member.Image==null)
        ? (object)SqlDbType.Image
        : member.Image);
```

unable to add null value to image column.

I get this error:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with image

Comment: Have you tried simply `("@Image", member.Image)` ?

Comment: Or using `DBNull.Value` also for the image parameter?

Comment: yes I have tried but it ask @image parameter value is not supplied

Comment: image type is actually byte[] . Conversion is not possible

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", (member.Image==null) ? (object)DBNull.Value : member.Image);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go: you're passing `SqlDbType.Image` (more commonly known as `7`) when you should be passing a *null*:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",
(member.Image==null)
    ? (object)DBNull.Value
    : member.Image);
```

If you want to specify the data type explicitly, do that separately; for example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",
(member.Image==null)
    ? (object)DBNull.Value
    : member.Image).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is only solution your problem

```
int filLength = 0;
byte[] byteImageArray;
byteImageArray = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(filLength)];
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",
    (member.Image==null)
        ? byteImageArray
        : member.Image);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you please elaborate and comment a little bit more on why this solution works?